# JavaRDD From IgniteRDD taking long time

Tags: java, apache-spark, ignite

I have created an Apache Ignite application with Spark

- Ignite Version - 1.6.0
- Spark Version - 1.5.2 (Built on Scala 2.11)

Application stores two tuples to IgniteRDD

When retrieve is called then collect function is taking more than 3 minutes.

Number of jobs submitted are more than 1000

Code snippet:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext;
import org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteRDD;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class CopyOfMainIgnite {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Demo").setMaster(
                "spark://169.254.228.183:7077");
        System.out.println("Spark conf initialized.");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        sc.addJar("./target/IgnitePOC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar");
        System.out.println("Spark context initialized.");
        IgniteContext ic = new IgniteContext(sc.sc(),
                "ignite/client-default-config.xml");
        System.out.println("Ignite Context initialized.");
        String cacheName = "demo6";
        save(sc, ic, cacheName);

        retrieve(ic, cacheName);
        ic.close(false);
        sc.close();

    }

    private static void retrieve(IgniteContext ic, String cacheName) {
        System.out.println("Getting IgniteRDD saved.");
        IgniteRDD<String, String> javaIRDDRet = ic.fromCache(cacheName);
        long temp1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> javardd = javaIRDDRet.toJavaRDD();
        System.out
                .println("Is empty Start Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("javaIRDDRet.isEmpty(): " + javardd.isEmpty());
        System.out.println("Is empty End Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        long temp2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long temp3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("collect and println Start Time: "
                + System.currentTimeMillis());
        javardd.collect().forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("collect and println End Time: "
                + System.currentTimeMillis());
        long temp4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Is empty : " + temp1 + " " + temp2
                + " Collect and print: " + temp3 + " " + temp4);
    }

    private static void save(JavaSparkContext sc, IgniteContext ic,
            String cacheName) {
        IgniteRDD<String, String> igniteRDD = ic.fromCache(cacheName);
        System.out.println("IgniteRDD from cache initialized.");
        Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        tempMap.put("Aditya", "Jain");
        tempMap.put("Pranjal", "Jaju");
        Tuple2<String, String> tempTuple1 = new Tuple2<String, String>(
                "Aditya", "Jain");
        Tuple2<String, String> tempTuple2 = new Tuple2<String, String>(
                "Pranjal", "Jaju");
        List<Tuple2<String, String>> list = new LinkedList<Tuple2<String, String>>();
        list.add(tempTuple1);
        list.add(tempTuple2);
        JavaPairRDD<String, String> jpr = sc.parallelizePairs(list, 4);
        System.out.println("Random RDD saved.");
        igniteRDD.savePairs(jpr.rdd(), false);
        System.out.println("IgniteRDD saved.");
    }
}
```

So my question: is it going to take 3-4 minutes to fetch 2 Rdd tuples from Ignite and collect them in my process?

Or is my expectation wrong that it will respond in milliseconds?

After debugging I found it is creating 1024 partitions in ignite rdd which is causing it to fire 1024 jobs. And i am not getting any way to control number of partitions.

Comment: What exactly is your question? So far, you only stated facts.

Comment: So my Question is - Is it going to take 3-4 Mins to fetch 2 Rdd Tuples From Ignite and Collect Them in My Process? or My Expectation is wrong that it will respond in Milliseconds.

Comment: It shouldn't take for so long time for sure. Do you start 1000 jobs like this in parallel? Is there any performance difference when you start a single job?

Comment: After debugging i found it is creating 1024 partitions in ignite rdd which is causing it to fire 1024 jobs. And i am not getting any way to control number of partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decrease number of partitions in `CacheConfiguration`:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    <property name="affinity">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
            <property name="partitions" value="32"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also you can use `IgniteRDD.sql(..)` and `IgniteRDD.objectSql(..)` methods to retrieve data directly from Ignite utilizing fast indexed search. For details on how to configure SQL in Ignite refer to this page: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries